# Как из PyQt запустить скрипт в cmd

Tags: python, pyqt

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from script import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess
import sys

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.runWallpaper) #Отвечает за смену обоев

    def runWallpaper(self):
        process = QProcess() #Присваивание к переменной QProcess

        args = ["run", "mpv", "--wid=132090", "test1.wmv", "--loop=inf", "--player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui", "--force-window=yes", "--no-audio"]

        # Приложение 'wp' должно быть прописано глобально, либо к нему должен быть указан путь
        process.start("<C:/Users/dooms/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/weebp-0.6.1-windows-x64/>wp", args);
        # ИЛИ
        # process->start("<путь/к/приложению/>wp", args);
        
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*Нужно чтобы при нажатие на кнопку выполнялась команда в cmd, как это реализовать?*

Comment: `import os; os.system("command")`?

Comment: А как в os.system поменять директорию и одновременно запустить команду?

Comment: путь надо указывать без угловых скобочек `<>`. К файлу "test1.wmv" тоже укажите путь

Comment: os.sytem("C:/Users/dooms/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/weebp-0.6.1-windows-x64/wp run mpv --wid=131998 test1.wmv --loop=inf --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui --force-window=yes --no-audio") Так? test.wmv находится там же

Comment: @olexxxi да, только `system()`, а не `sytem()` Либо `cd directory && command`.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло

Comment: А можно же написать прогу с os.system(Моя команда) Скомпелировать ее и уже через другой пайтон файл открыть ее как exe

Comment: import os, sys

cmd_start = os.system("cd C:/Users/dooms/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/weebp-0.6.1-windows-x64/test.exe")

Comment: Пишет неверное имя папки((